# Setting up GitHub Pages with Custom Domain

Tags: github, dns, hosting, github-pages, http-status-code-403

I hosted my website using GitHub Pages and was fully functional at

```
my-github-username.github.io
```

**Please Note: 'my-github-username' is just a placeholder

But I wanted to use it with a domain that I already had purchased so I looked it up and found some articles but none were helpful.

So far I added the custom domain to my GitHub repository. 
I also created a CNAME record pointing to my-github-username.github.io
I also created 'A' records with 4 IP addresses that I found on GitHub documentation.

When I type my-github-username.github.io it points me to my domain successfully but it gives me a

> 403 Forbidden Error

and says

> "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you actually checked the web server logs - `403` is access denied on `http` rather than something dns related. You might find an access list of something is blocking your access

Comment: Right, so my domain that I have is not https domain it is just http. Is that the reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you share your domain name? This looks like a http server config issue *not* a dns issue. You might test by making a folder on your web path with a test.html file inside and see if you can navigate directly to that rather then the project/home page.

Comment: I had this problem when trying to publish on Github pages a (private) repo while publishing the root (/) folder, which was not the root of the website. In the repo, make sure you publish your site in `docs` (and not e.g. `public` for hugo), then in the settings of the repo select publish `docs/` in `master` branch. My guess is that 403 denial is the only thing github can show if you try to publish the wrong folder of a private repository...